# Network Discovery Checking using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, network-programming, vb.net-2010

Good day people! I just want to ask if there's a way to check if the Network Discovery button in windows os if it's on/off using VB.NET. I manage to find a code using cmd but it only enables me to turn it on/off but what i need is to check if it's on/off. Any ideas? Thanks!